# iPad - Why won't my label update?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, uilabel

I have a timer running and I'd like it to update my score every time it ticks. Here is the code I have. It will initialize fine, the score integer will update, but the label will never update from 0.

```
    score = score+1;
scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
[scoreLabel setNeedsDisplay];
```

Now, a previous question I had got an answer that mentioned UI updates only work on the main thread so right now it's set up like this:

```
-(void) updateGame:(NSTimer *)timer{
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateScore) 
                           withObject:nil 
                        waitUntilDone:false];
```

}

but still no luck. Can anybody point me in the right direction? I haven't had a problem like this before.

Comment: Does scoreLabel really point to your label? Your code seems find.

Comment: Have you checked that `scoreLabel` is not nil? If it's an `IBOutlet`, check that you have it connected in IB.

Comment: scoreLabel does points to it, I just checked. At least that's what I refer to when I set up it's visual attributes.

Comment: pgb, I'm creating the scoreLabel in code. I declare it at the top of the M file with:
UILabel* scoreLabel;
then I declare all the attributes with...
oh my god when I went to copy it I saw the first line was 
UILabel *scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
I removed the duplicate UILabel and it ran perfect. Thanks for making me check code I assumed was fine!

Answer (score 0):

Is the timer notification arriving from a thread that's not the main thread?  You can't update UI from other threads.